# How to implement the dislike-like button

Tags: html

I am developing a web page with rating mechanism, so I need two buttons called "dislike" and "like", once clicked, the rating information would be sent to the server to update the related rating information. What html code should I use, could you give a little code for doing this?

Comment: It depends on the server side.  Does it require a form submission or a web service call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

erm... you can't really do that with html alone, mate. You need a server-side script to handle that. Suggest Php.

After that, use a GET or POST method to carry your like or dislike vote to the server-side script.

Answer (score 1):

**I am leaving this answer in case if someone else faces this problem in future :**

As said by Kaleb , this functionality can not be achieved by html itself, **database is must for this** because once you close the html page your upvote and downvote counter will be gone.

What you need to do is :

1. In your database , make a table say **"votes"** .
2. This table should have following columns

   - voteup  - this should be filled with two options either **yes** or **no**
   - votedown - this should also be filled with two values "**yes**" or "**no**"
   - voteup_count -This will count the total of upvotes
   - vote_down - This will count the total of downvotes

   **Working**

   - Before rendering your html page , check the corresponding entries into database whether the particular post is already upvoted  or downvoted
   - If the post is **upvoted** and you again click the **upvoted** button the button text should change from **upvoted** to **upvote** and the counter should be decremented by 1 in the database as well under the **voteup_count** column
   - If the post is neither **upvoted** nor **downvoted** whenever the button is clicked it should increment the respective counter and then again change the button text either to **upvoted** or **downvoted**
   - ***of course your like and dislike button should also be dynamically created for each form.***

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="ratings">
    <input type="button" name="btnLike" value="Like">
    <input type="button" name="btnDislike" value="Dislike">
</form>
```

Then whatever code you use to check the answer should accept the value of the button as a parameter for the update.

Comment: This answer is heading in the right direction, but the name attribute is deprecated (in favour of id), forms need an action, and the buttons should be of type "submit" — otherwise they won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a form. Here is an example I've copied from the Internet.
`<form action="mulsub.asp" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br/>
<input type="submit" name="bsubmit" value="Submit 1">`

<input type="submit" name="bsubmit" value="Submit 2">
<input type="submit" name="bsubmit" value="Submit 3">
</form>
Check it out on [this webpage](http://www.chami.com/tips/internet/042599I.html). Programmed in ASP, I hate that language by the way :)